# How to display the Linux kernel command line parameters given for the current boot?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

In the `grub.conf` configuration file I can specify command line parameters that the kernel will use, i.e.:

```
kernel /boot/kernel-3-2-1-gentoo root=/dev/sda1 vga=791
```

After booting a given kernel, is there a way to display the command line parameters that were passed to the kernel in the first place? I've found sysctl,

```
sysctl --all
```

but sysctl shows up *all* possible kernel parameters.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

```
$ cat /proc/cmdline
root=/dev/xvda xencons=tty console=tty1 console=hvc0 nosep nodevfs ramdisk_size=32768 ip_conntrack.hashsize=8192 nf_conntrack.hashsize=8192 ro  devtmpfs.mount=1 
$
```

Answer (score 14):

The kernel also printks them at the beginning of boot, see:

```
dmesg | grep "Command line"
```

Sample output:

```
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.4.0-112-generic root=/dev/mapper/vg00-root ro
```

This can be useful information on the serial if you are hacking stuff and the kernel [panics instead of booting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104771/where-are-kernel-panic-logs/932380#932380) :-)

Related: [How do I find the boot parameters used by the running kernel? | Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32654/how-do-i-find-the-boot-parameters-used-by-the-running-kernel)